# How do I write a for loop that checks around the current object using slices?

Tags: python, list, slice

beginner programmer!

sorry for the strangely worded question. I'm not sure how to word it; I might just be googling the wrong thing :/

I want to check for patches in a list that have 3 zeros in a row and change the middle 0 into a 2. For example:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

would become

```
[0, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```

the second 0 became a two because the function detected 3 zeros in a row and changed the middle zero into a 2.

I used slices to write a for loop like this:

```
# create function
def test(lst):
# for loop for every object in list--
for i in lst:
    # creates slice object.
    #         calls index method            does the same here
    #         to find item index            except it adds one
    #         then subtracts one            to make the slice 3 objects
    slce = str(lst.index(i) - 1) + ":" + str(lst.index(i) + 2)
    print(slce)
```

It's not really a slice, it's a string, but I wanted to print it. I used this same code as an actual slice.

It's supposed to return:

```
-1:2
0:3
1:4
2:5
```

and so on and so forth, but instead it returns

```
-1:2
0:3
0:3
0:3
0:3
```

Any ideas? thank you guys for your help!

Comment: list.index return first index of value, so you got same 'slice' string if same value in your list.

Comment: the example you gave, and the result you want is contradictive, since after the value 2 was placed, there was no more 3 zeroes in a row, so isn't the program supposed to stop there? If there was some error in your explanation, could you elaborate properly?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you attempted using `a.index(i)` as it wil not always be correct because it returns the first occurance of `i`.

A better approach would be to slide a window on the array and check for the condition.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
slices = [(i, i+3) for i in range(len(a) - 2)]    # Generate slices

for i, j in slices:
  if all(x == 0 for x in a[i:j]):   # Check if all elements in the subarray are zero
    a[i+1] = 2                      # Change middle element
```

I generated a slices array to match your initial approach but you can skip this step. The code can be reduced to just a signle loop:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

for i in range(len(a) - 2):
  if all(x == 0 for x in a[i:i+3]):
    a[i+1] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

not realy sure what your purpose is here, but i would imagine it would look something like this, dunno if that works.

```
from random import randint

data = []
for i in range(100): data.append(randint(0,1))

print(data)


for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if data[i:i+3] == [0,0,0] and data[i-1] != 2: # made an edit
        data[i:i+3] = [0,2,0]

print(data)
```